# File not getting read using file_get_html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using curl to store webpage in txt file and then reading the file to parse its content.
For some website its running fine but for some websites it is(file_get_html) returning null.
I have checked that txt file is generated with data but it is unable read the content.

For this website when i use direct link in file_get_html at that time also it returns null.
I have added user agent but not working.
Finally i removed all the content from file except one div  tag at that time it read the content.

Kindly suggest why is it happening like this?

Comment: "it is unable"? What it? curl? the webpage? file_get_contents?

Comment: file_get_html is returning null.. txt file is getting populated with data

Comment: Probably the html is malformed. Have you tried running it through a validator?

Comment: validator means??? haven't tried anything like that.. can you elaborate how to do that?

Comment: First, make sure that file_get_contents can get data. If it can, file_get_html will be able to load data to simplehtml Dom.