# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - FIle not being read

Tags: php, object, wamp, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I've written a script to process html files from URLs, however, due to a 30's script runtime restriction with my cheap host provider I've had to alter the script to store the html as txt files and run it from a local WAMP server.

I am trying to load each file up, extract what I need, then move onto the next file.

URL's as source `file_get_html` was doing the job perfectly (I could ->find the required elements)
Txt file as source `file_get_html` is returning a blank object.

Based on some advice in the below post I changed `file_get_html` for `file_get_contents` which created an array with a single large string containing the contents of the text file.

*First, make sure that `file_get_contents` can get data. If it can, `file_get_htm`l will be able to load data to `simplehtml` Dom*

If `file_get_contents` returns a string, which it does, how would I "*load data to simplehtml Dom*?"

[File not getting read using file_get_html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115793/file-not-getting-read-using-file-get-html)

I then tried to convert the string into an object `str_get_html`, however, this didn't work either.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('file.txt');
var_dump($html);
```

Returns: `object(simple_html_dom)[1]`  but with no other contents or arrays.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_contents('file.txt');
var_dump($html);
```

Returns: `string < ! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC.....`

**Questions**:

Can anyone give me any advice? What's the best way to load up a text file containing html markup into an object so that I can utilise the find method on it's contents. I want to avoid loading the file into an array of strings and using regex to process contents.

Are there any considerations I need to make if using a local WAMP server?

Comment: Can you post your code and text file you are trying to read ?

Comment: I managed to fix it using str_get_html after i'd used file_get_contents to open the file. The text file is literally html source code dump of a webpage  e.g.<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>.......

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in a question. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I managed to solve this myself. I am sure i'd already tried to extract html from string, doh!

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_contents('file.txt');    
$html = str_get_html($html);
var_dump($html)
```

> Returns `object(simple_html_dom)[1]` including all expected arrays etc
>
> Instead of trying to create the html object directly from the source file using `file_get_html` I've extracted the file contents `file_get_contents` then converted str to html using `str_get_html` which allows me to use the simple html dom methods e.g. find on attributes within the object e.g.

```
$html->find('a');
```